# How to highlight selected/clicked cell of a table HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am working on a simple project to learn web development and I would like to add a feature in my project that highlights the clicked cell to a specific colour. Please have a look at this link: https://jsfiddle.net/pz6tc3ae/30/

What this project does is, when any cell from table 1 is clicked it triggers table 2, however, currently there is no way of knowing which table cell triggered table 2, so I am thinking of adding a feature that highlights the clicked cell, however, when the user clicks away from the highlighted cell, the cell should change colour to the one it was in before being highlighted, and not to the default colour.

Please note, try the link above in chrome, some features does not work other browsers.

**HTML**

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<body>
<table width="300" border="1" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell2"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell3"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell4"> On-Menu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell5"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell6"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell7"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell8"> On-Menu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell9"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell10"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell11"> On-Menu</td>
      <td id="cell12"> On-Menu</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="300" border="1" id="menulist">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cellorange"> Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cellapple"> Apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="cellbanana"> Banana</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

If my question was  not clear, please let me know and I will try explaining it better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
https://jsfiddle.net/pz6tc3ae/35/

just add to javascript:

```
actionCell.className = (actionCell.className === "green") ? "none" : "green";
```

and to CSS:

```
.green{background:green;}
```

This is the demo with jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/pz6tc3ae/37/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it changes the colour of the cell when clicked but also, I want it to change back to the colour it was previously in when user clicks on another cell.

Comment: You can use removeClass when user clicks outside.

Comment: It still won't change to the previous colour

Comment: with javascript its bit complected but then also this works now check it.
Check Fiddle.

Comment: Works now, btw is it possible to instead of getting a colour from a class to get colour from anther cell id. e.g. change to colour to the colour of another cell?

Comment: say for example, in this case id="cellapple" (take the colour from its id and not the class linked to this)

Comment: actionCell.className = (actionCell.className === document.getElementById('cellapple').className) ? "none" : document.getElementById('cellapple').className;

Comment: Found a small bug, so when user clicks table 1 to toggle table 2 and click on a cell in table 2, it changes the colour of the cell in table 1 to the colour. Having the colour changed to a cell in table 2, this highlighting function does not work.

Comment: that's bit confusing i suggest you to use jquery.

Comment: jquery for highlighting the selected cell?

Comment: jquery make this task in very easier way

Comment: Thanks, so instead of taking the colour from a class like you have, can I take the colour from another cell using the code you wrote? 
   
 
actionCell.className = (actionCell.className === document.getElementById('cellapple').className) ? "none" : document.getElementById('cellapple').className;

Comment: color from another cell copies the style element which is hard to override so instead of applying inline style class would be much better.